# Method with const parameter does not accept non-const parameter?

Tags: c++, constants, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

This code does not compile:

```cpp
ErrorTolerantSearch e;
e.readStringsFromFile("test.txt");
e.buildQgramIndex(3);
vector<map<uint, uint>*> lists;
lists.push_back(&e._qgramIndex["ret"]); // ignore this, assume container not empty
lists.push_back(&e._qgramIndex["coo"]); // ignore this, assume container not empty
map<uint, uint> resunion = e.computeUnion(lists); // <-- this makes problems
```

This is a part of the header

```cpp
class ErrorTolerantSearch {
 public:
  void readStringsFromFile(string fileName);
  void buildQgramIndex(uint  q);
  map<uint, uint> computeUnion(const vector<const map<uint, uint>*> & lists);
  map<string, map<uint, uint> > _qgramIndex;
};
```

This is the error the compiler gives:

```
ErrorTolerantSearchTest.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void ErrorTolerantSearchTest_computeUnion_Test::TestBody()’:
ErrorTolerantSearchTest.cpp:89:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘ErrorTolerantSearch::computeUnion(std::vector<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>*>&)’
ErrorTolerantSearchTest.cpp:89:50: note: candidate is:
In file included from ErrorTolerantSearchTest.cpp:36:0:
./ErrorTolerantSearch.h:56:19: note: std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> ErrorTolerantSearch::computeUnion(const std::vector<const std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>*>&)
./ErrorTolerantSearch.h:56:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>*>’ to ‘const std::vector<const std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>*>&’
make[1]: *** [ErrorTolerantSearchTest] Fehler 1
```

But what is the problem? I dont get it. I never had problems with passing non-const variables to functions with const parameters by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<const T>` is not equal to `std::vector<T>` and no convertible to it.